# Can you draw power from the ADUM4160 USB isolator

Tags: power-supply, pcb, circuit-design, usb, isolation

I am developing a USB powered medical device and I am thinking of using the **ADUM4160** to isolate the USB from the device.

However, there is one thing i didn't understand about the device: does it isolate the power lines and **can I use them to power the device at USB 2.0 power (500mA)**?

If not, Is there an AIO component to isolate data+power?

Comment: Looking at the datasheet, the ADUM4160 does ***not*** seem to provide isolated power as well. I believe ADI has several USB isolators, one of which I think did power too (albeit only 50-100mA). Failing that, Murata has a much chunkier equivalent that can do the full 500mA (and I think it met medical isolation requirements), I don't recall the part number though. ADI also has a dedicated SOIC-8 isolated DC-DC you can pair with the data isolator (I forget its current limit though)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will look into them

Comment: Since you mention a _medical device_, which isolation requirements does the design need to meet?

Answer (score 2):

No. the ADUM4160 only isolates. It does not supply VBUS. You need to supply either VBUSx or VDDx on both sides.

Assuming you want to build a host with an isolated USB port, you can use just about any isolated DC/DC converter to supply the device side.

If you don't need a lot of power and you must use an Analog devices part; the [ADUM5010](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM5010.pdf) can supply up to 150 mW.

Answer (score 0):

> *If not, Is there an AIO component to isolate data+power?*

There are a few such as the [ADuM5400](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adum5400.html): -

[image]

It has a 500 mW power converter. The output can be used to power ADCs and some other analogue circuits so that you can build an isolated signal converter.

There is also the [ADuM5401](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adum5401_5402_5403_5404.pdf) and this has 3 IO lines pointing left to right and one IO line pointing right to left. The data sheet also shows other variants (all of which have incorporated a 500 mW isolated power supply): -

[image]

So, you pretty much have all the options covered. But, you will still have to make a USB interface for these devices.